# Identify modified rows from updated Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I collect data and analyze. In this case , there are a times data collected like yesterday or last week missing a value and might get updated when records are available at a later date, or a row value might change. I mean a row value might be modified, see sample dataframe:

**First dataframe to receive**

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Date': ['2020-09-11','2020-10-11','2021-01-12','2020-01-03', '2021-02-01'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Mercedes'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000,45000],
        'Mileage': [2000,'NAN',47000,3500,5000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Date','Brand', 'Price', 'Mileage'])

print (df)
```

**Modification done on first dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

cars2 = {'Date': ['2020-09-11','2020-10-11','2021-01-12','2020-01-03', '2021-02-01'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Mercedes'],
        'Price': [22000,5000,27000,35000,45000],
        'Mileage': [2000,100,47000,3500,600]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['Date','Brand', 'Price', 'Mileage'])

print (df2)
```

Now I did like to know how I can select only rows modified from first dataframe. My expected output is only get rows which were modified at a later date . I have tried this  but it gives me old rows too

```
df_diff = pd.concat([df,df2], sort=False).drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)
```

**Expected output**

```
import pandas as pd

cars3 = {'Date': ['2020-10-11', '2021-02-01'],
        'Brand': ['Toyota Corolla','Mercedes'],
        'Price': [5000,45000],
        'Mileage': [100,600]
        }

df3 = pd.DataFrame(cars3, columns = ['Date','Brand', 'Price', 'Mileage'])

print (df3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are same index and columns is possible use [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for compare for not equal and test if at least one row `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df3 = df2[df.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
print (df3)
         Date           Brand  Price  Mileage
1  2020-10-11  Toyota Corolla   5000      100
4  2021-02-01        Mercedes  45000      600
```

Comment: what of a case where , new rows have been added, will it capture them too?

Comment: @LivingstoneM - Then need `new = df2[~df2.index.isin(df.index)]` for get new rows.